# Writing android tests for custom layouts that extend design library layouts

Tags: java, android, testing, android-testing

I'm trying to test a custom layout, which extends `TextInputLayout` from the design library. When i run the test, i get the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>   at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
>   at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:192)
>   at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:185)
>   at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:181)

I'm using the context provided by `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to instantiate the custom layout. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hey, maybe answers here will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Answer (score 0):

Call `setTheme()` on the context object providing it with an AppCompat theme before using it to instantiate the custom layout, as shown in the example test method below.

```
@Test
public void testCustomLayout() {
    Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
    context.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
    CustomLayout textInputEditText = new CustomLayout(context);
    assertNotNull(textInputEditText);
}
```